# Linear Functional $f$ whose nullity is the subspace {($x,y,z$)|$x=y$ & $z=0$}.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

What can be the Linear Functional $f$ from $R^3$ to $R$ whose nullity is the subspace {($x,y,z$)|$x=y$ & $z=0$}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N:=\{(x,y,z): x=y, z=0\}$. Then $ \dim N=1$.

Suppose that there is a linear functional $f: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ with $\ker(f)=N$.

It is clear that $\dim f( \mathbb R^3)=1$. Then we have:

$3 = \dim \mathbb R^3= \dim N+ \dim f( \mathbb R^3)=1+1=2$,

a contradiction.